# Laravel how to check if url param is in array otherwise use general router

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm using router in Laravel and my routes file is like this

```
Route::get('/{product_slug}', 'HomeController@subpage');
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('/signup', 'AuthController@signup');

Route::get('/products', 'HomeController@products');
Route::get('/product/{product_id}', 'HomeController@product_detail');
```

if `/{product_slug}` is in array ('product_a', 'product_b') use `HomeController@subpage` but if not use following route.

for example,

If user enter `www.sample.co/product_a` it will use `HomeController@subpage`

but if user enter `www.sample.co/signup` it will use `AuthController@signup`

how can I setup the routes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The order matters. If you put them like this:

```
Route::get('/{product_slug}', 'HomeController@subpage');
// ...
Route::get('/signup', 'AuthController@signup');
// ...
```

It will evaluate the `/{product_slug}` route first. This means, you'll need to add logic to know if the request wants to go to the `signup`route.

If you do this instead:

```
Route::get('/signup', 'AuthController@signup');
// ...
Route::get('/{product_slug}', 'HomeController@subpage');
// ...
```

Your app will evaluate the `/signup` first and then go to the `/{product_slug}`. So there's no need to add extra validation. You'll need to just validate your business logic: if the slug belongs to a product.

```
public function subpage(Request $request)
{
    Product::whereSlug($request->get('product_slug'))->firstOrFail();
    // ...
}
```

---

As a side note, I suggest you to add a route differentiator to your endpoint, to avoid this kind of situations:

```
Route::get('/slug/{product_slug}', 'HomeController@subpage');
//          ^^^^^^
```